# Ping packets not seen in packet captures

Tags: wireshark, ping, icmp

Could not see ping request or response packets in WireShark.

I am pinging to a static IP and capturing the same via WireShark. The ping is successful. However, in the capture files, I could not see any ping request or response files. Could someone explain what might be wrong here?

[No ICMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpxvD.png)

Comment: Are you sure you're capturing on the right interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be sure with the very little info you provided. However, since there is a possibility of a dual stack here, you can try using the below filter.

```
icmp || icmpv6
```